# Liferay 7 Extending FlagsRequestMessageListener

Tags: liferay, liferay-7, message-listener

We're using Liferay 7 and I was wondering if there is a way to extend the FlagsRequestMessageListener class. As I understand, it is not possible to extend core liferay classes, instead we have to use the exposed API's.

I want to have a custom implementation of the getRecipients method to be able to retrieve recipients who have a custom role. (By default it sends the email to either the site owner, organization owner or admin).

In Liferay 6.2 I could simply extend this class and override the getRecipients method, but now com.liferay.flags osgi modules don't export the required packages (with FlagsRequestMessageListener and FlagsRequest classes).

Is it possible to do that in Liferay 7?

For info - I've also posted this question in Liferay community forum (https://web.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/104715293). Not sure what the fuss is about - I'm trying to solve the issue I'm facing, It's my understanding that StackOverflow is a much larger community and I might be able to get help.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141823/why-is-cross-posting-wrong-on-an-external-site

Comment: Included information about the post in liferay community forums

Comment: re your comment in the question/answer: It's well laid out in the meta question: You're asking for free help (which we're all happy to give), just please don't generate duplicate work, e.g. when one side is long solved, the other still looks like someone desperately looking for help.